# turning a if(button.g == 1) to auto run in 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, java, minecraft, autorun

I'm trying to add to this code so it will auto-run the string for button.g == 1, after 10 seconds of not clicking the button.

```
  {
    if(button.g == 0)
    {
        f.a(parent);
        AutoJoin.instance.resetCache();
    }
    if(button.g == 1)
    {
        AutoJoin.instance.screen = new AutoJoinScreen(parent, info);
        f.a(AutoJoin.instance.screen);
    }
    if(button.g == 2)
        f.a(new PropertiesScreen(this, info.ip));
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to "delay" an action:

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log('I'm 10 secs later'); }, 1000*10);
```

With [`clearTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) you can abort such a timer:

```
var timer = setTimeout(/* .... */);
clearTimeout(timer)
```

In your example you could start a timeout which executes the logic for `button.g == 1` and cancel the timer if any button is clicked:

Setting the timer to 10s:

```
var timer = setTimeout(1000*10, function() { 
  AutoJoin.instance.screen = new AutoJoinScreen(parent, info);
    f.a(AutoJoin.instance.screen);
 })
```

Click routine:

```
clearTimeout(timer);

if(button.g == 0) {
    f.a(parent);
    AutoJoin.instance.resetCache();
} 
else if if(button.g == 1) {
    AutoJoin.instance.screen = new AutoJoinScreen(parent, info);
    f.a(AutoJoin.instance.screen);
}
else if(button.g == 2) {
    f.a(new PropertiesScreen(this, info.ip));
}
```